# Split a single Excel row into multiple based on columns

Tags: excel, vbe

I need to create multiple Excel rows based off of a single row.  For example, I currently have a single row for each personnel and there are dozens of columns that are "grouped" so to speak.  So say column K is its own group, then columns M, N, O are a group, P, Q, R, are a group, etc.  I need that single row to become multiple rows - one row per group of columns.  So the current situation is:

```
1 | Smith, John | Column K | Column M | Column N | Column O | Column P | Column Q| Column R
```

And I need that to become:

```
1 | Smith, John | Column K

2 | Smith, John | Blank | Column M | Column N | Column O

3 | Smith, John | Blank |   Blank  |  Blank   | Blank    | Column P | Column Q | Column R
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution. You probably can do that math a bit smarter. I can't right now. ;)

```
Sub splitRows()

Dim i As Integer

With Sheets(1)
For i = 2 To (.UsedRange.Columns.Count / 3)

.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Value = .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 3)).Value
.Range(Cells(i, (i - 1) * 3 + 1), Cells(i, (i - 1) * 3 + 3)).Value = .Range(Cells(1, (i - 1) * 3 + 1), Cells(1, (i - 1) * 3 + 3)).Value

Next

End With

End Sub
```

This will only work correctly for sheets where there are always groups of three columns. If not, you have to change that `.UsedRange.Columns.Count / 3` part.

Cheers.